# How to calculate total minutes in current time Python

Tags: python

i want to get total number of minute in current time

from time import gmtime, strftime

class Time:

```
def __init__(self,hours,minutes):
    self.hours=hours
    self.minutes=minutes
    print('{} hour {} minutes'.format(self.hours,self.minutes))

@staticmethod
def time():
    now = datetime.now()
    current = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("Current Time =", current)

def current_time(self):
    pass
```

t=Time(1,2)
t.time()

Comment: total minutes means what ? do u want to convert hours to minute + available minutes or what ?

Answer (score 2):

[`datetime.datetime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print(now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

Comment: maybe total_minutes = now.hour*60+ now.minute?

Comment: Depends how OP means "total number of minute in current time." `now.hour*60` would imply "minutes since start of day", since [`datetime.hour`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.hour) is in `range(24)`.

Comment: I agree "total_minutes" is poorly defined ... maybe since jan 1 1970 ? or maybe since 2000-01-01 or maybe just since the begining of the hour ...